# Disable functional and acceptance test in Yii2

Tags: php, testing, yii2, codeception

I'm starting using **codeception** in **Yii2** to perform unit tests, functional tests and acceptance tests.

I would focus on the unit tests for the moment.

So, I looking for the appropriate way to disable functional tests and acceptance tests without deleting my existing tests files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only unit tests and run only them. For running only unit tests use `codecept run unit`

Comment: @vitalik_74 is it mandatory to use `yii2_advanced_tests` db, can I use my live db?